# .NET ListView not populating on control selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview

I have a ListView in .NET that is hooked up to various CRUD methods, the select method that accepts a value doesn't seem to be working. The Data Source is supposed to be taking the value from a drop down list control, taking the selected value. when I do the configure data source method in visual studio, I select this method for my select operation:

```
EntReqList_byID(Int32 programID), returns List<EntranceRequirementInfo>
```

Then when I define parameters in the next part of the wizard, I pick control as a parameter source, with the control ID set to CertificateList, which shows the programID as the parameter from CertificateList.SelectedValue.

When I run the page, and select an item from the CertificateList, and click "Show Program", all my data is pulled except for that in the list view. My code is as follows:

The top of my page:

Please select the program credential type:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="InitialCredential" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="InitialCredential_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>[Select]</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Certificate</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Diploma</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Degree</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
    Please select a program:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="CertificateList" runat="server" DataSourceID="CertificateODS" DataTextField="ProgramName" DataValueField="ProgramID" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DiplomaList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DiplomaListODS" DataTextField="ProgramName" DataValueField="ProgramID" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DegreeList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DegreeListODS" DataTextField="DegreeName" DataValueField="DegreeID" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowUpdateFields" runat="server" OnClick="ShowUpdateFields_Click">Show Program</asp:LinkButton>
</p>
```

My ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="EntReqListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntranceReqODS" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CourseIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CourseNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CourseIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CourseNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr runat="server" style="">
                                    <th runat="server"></th>
                                    <th runat="server">ProgramID</th>
                                    <th runat="server">CourseID</th>
                                    <th runat="server">CourseName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">Mark</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server" style="">
                            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProgramIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProgramID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="MarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mark") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

My Code behind:

```
protected void InitialCredential_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //display programs DDL based on credential choice
    if(InitialCredential.SelectedValue == "Certificate")
    {
        CertificateList.Visible = true;
        DiplomaList.Visible = false;
        DegreeList.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (InitialCredential.SelectedValue == "Diploma")
    {
        CertificateList.Visible = false;
        DiplomaList.Visible = true;
        DegreeList.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (InitialCredential.SelectedValue == "Degree")
    {
        CertificateList.Visible = false;
        DiplomaList.Visible = false;
        DegreeList.Visible = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        CertificateList.Visible = false;
        DiplomaList.Visible = false;
        DegreeList.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void CredentialType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (CredentialType.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "Diploma":
            {
                entrance_req.Visible = true;
                degree_link.Visible = false;
                degree_pathways.Visible = true;
            }
            break;
        case "Certificate":
            {
                entrance_req.Visible = true;
                degree_link.Visible = false;
                degree_pathways.Visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "Degree":
            {
                entrance_req.Visible = false;
                degree_link.Visible = true;
                degree_pathways.Visible = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                entrance_req.Visible = false;
                degree_link.Visible = false;
                degree_pathways.Visible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}

protected void ShowUpdateFields_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    show_update_form.Visible = true;




    if (InitialCredential.SelectedValue == "Certificate")
    {
        DiplomaCertificate certificate = new DiplomaCertificate();
        PathwaysController controller = new PathwaysController();

        certificate = controller.CertificateProgram_byID(int.Parse(CertificateList.SelectedValue));

        ProgramName.Text = certificate.ProgramName;
        CategoryList.SelectedValue = certificate.CategoryID.ToString();
        CredentialType.SelectedValue = "Certificate";
        ProgramLength.Text = certificate.ProgramLength;
        ProgramLink.Text = certificate.ProgramLink;
        Activated.Checked = certificate.Activated;
        WorkOutdoors.Checked = certificate.WorkOutdoors;
        ShiftWork.Checked = certificate.ShiftWork;
        Travel.Checked = certificate.WorkTravel;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing to make it get the programID, and populate the data?

Comment: Seems to me you are reacting at the change event of the InitialCredential dropdownlist, but you want to react at the CertificateList dropdownlist selection change event

Comment: the Initial Credit is just there to hide/show a particular DDL. CertificateList is the control I am trying to take data from, but the listView isnt even being generated with an empty item tempate, when you catually run the page there is no evidence of it anywhere